# Prove that $p$ is Composite by Showing that It is Not a Pseudoprime Basis $2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pseudoprimes

I have the following problem:
Prove that $m \notin \mathbb{P} $ by showing that m is not a pseudoprime to the basis $2$.
I think normally the problem is not that difficult, but in this case $m= 3363148097 $, which makes it very difficult to find its prime factorization and other properties that could help solve the problem.   Also trying to actually calculate the modulo by breaking the power $^{m-1}$ is complicated.            I think I might be missing something about the fact that the base is 2, maybe there are some more properties for that...

Answer (score 1):

You want to compute $2^{m-1}\bmod m$. Note that you can find $2^{2k}\bmod m$ from $2^k\bmod m$ by a single multiplication modulo $m$, and $2^{2k+1}\bmod m$ from $2^k\bmod m$ by a single addition modulo $m$. Thus to compute $2^{m-1}\bmod m$  amounts to less than thirty multiplications modulo $m$ and a handful additions modulo $m$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Dividing out factors of $2$ from $m-1$ shows that
$$m-1=336148096=2^7\times2626157,$$
which allows you to factor $2^{m-1}-1$ as follows:
$$2^{m-1}-1=2^{2^7\times2626157}-1=(2^{2626157}-1)\prod_{k=0}^6(2^{2^k\times2626157}+1).$$

Comment: I eddited $m$, but the factorization is the same way. thaks!

Comment: sorry, I am still not able to see how to use the factorization without doing many calculations

Comment: by the way, with the new $m$ I have $m=2^6\times 5674189$

Comment: No; with the new $m$ you have $m-1=2^6\times52549189$, and the large factor is easily seen to be divisible by $7$ and $11$.

Comment: Sorry, but I still find it rather difficult to see how to calcular with such big exponents and $m$.

Comment: Is there maybe a method to simplify this kind of problems or is breaking the exponent the only one?

Comment: My last comment suggests that it is easy to check that
$$m-1=2^6\times52549189=2^6\times7\times11\times682457.$$
The latter takes a little effort to factor by hand, but is not that hard either. Anyway, you can again use the fact that
$$X^n-1=\prod_{d\mid n}\Phi_d(X),$$
to compute $\gcd(2^{m-1}-1,m)$ by computing the gcd for the smaller factors.

Answer (score 0):

Let $m = 3363148097$. Now, if $m$ is prime, then $m | 2^{m-1}$.

If $m$ is a pseudoprime, then $m | 2^{m-1}$.

Hence, if $m \nmid 2^{m-1}$, then $m$ must be composite.